# libGDX JglfwApplication vs LwjglApplication

Tags: libgdx

Can someone explain the difference between LwjglApplication and a JglfwApplication?

What do the 2 acronyms Lwgl and Jglf  stand for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [words](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2915) of the libgdx project lead:

> Nate and I have been working on a new desktop backend based on GLFW.
>   It’s almost complete, audio is the last bit we need to tackle. GLFW
>   may allow us to target non-desktop platforms in the future more
>   easily, and also solves some issues with Mac OS X and Java 7 we
>   currently have with the LWJGL backend (LWJGL guys are working on it,
>   Nate needed something now for Spine…). For now LWJGL will stay the
>   default, but we may eventually make the GLFW backend the default.

**LwjglApplication** and **JglfwApplication** are just 2 different Desktop Backends. One uses LWJGL and the other GLFW.

[GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) is:

> GLFW is an Open Source, multi-platform library for creating windows
>   with OpenGL contexts and managing input and events. It is easy to
>   integrate into existing applications and does not lay claim to the
>   main loop.
>
> GLFW is written in C and has native support for Windows, OS X and many
>   Unix-like systems using the X Window System, such as Linux and
>   FreeBSD.

**What do the 2 acronyms Lwgl and Jglf stand for?**

**LWJGL** stands for **LightWeight Java Game Library**.
But **GLFW** is a little more vague, taken from their [Wiki](http://wiki.glfw.org/wiki/GLFW) :p

> GLFW used to stand for OpenGL Framework, but since it isn't really a
>   framework, here are some alternate meanings:
>
> ```
> Good Luck Finding Willy
> OpenGL and Fine Windows
> Galactic Library Funding Wars
> Given Long Flights, Wait
> Games Live For Windows
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Generous answer